# UITextField setting backgroundcolor hides shadow

Tags: iphone, background, uitextfield, shadow

So I'm customizing my UITextField.layer with a shadow:

```
[userNameField.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:180/255.0 green:180/255.0 blue:180/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
[userNameField.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
[userNameField.layer setCornerRadius:6.0];
[userNameField.layer setShadowOpacity:0.7];
[userNameField.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:180/255.0 green:180/255.0 blue:180/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
[userNameField.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5)];
```

This works like a charm but the background is transparent.
Now when I set the background color:

```
[userNameField.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
```

The shadow is overwritten (hidden by the background color).

Does anyone know how to set both the background color AND the shadow on a text field?

Comment: I had the same problem that when I was trying to set a shadow on a textfield it wasn't working / appearing, I  didn't realise it was because I had set the backgroundColor, so +1 to the OP for that!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to explicitly set the `masksToBounds` property of the `UITextField` layer to NO like so:

```
myTextField.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

Answer (score -2):

You can set margin:

```
myTextField.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 7, 7)];
```

Try this